# PHP MySQL - Fetching result but no output

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I am at my witts end here.
I have a table full with feedback data for restaurants and I am working on creating a scorecard website where the user can filter

1. the year of the record (column: Date)
2. the restaurant / outlet name (column: Outlet)
3. the property it is located in (a unique 5 digit code - column: Holidex)

After the submission of the filters and the building of the queries, I am trying to display the data in a table, but the problem is that the table itself is never generated...

I suspect an error while fetching the row, but cannot seem to find the issue.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
    $mcount = $row['ID'];
    $mydata = stats("ALLMYRECORDS", "ALLMYRECORDS", "ALLMYRECORDS", "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
```

Would appreciate some help here please as I am new to the MySQLi part of things and am not sure what to do. Thank you.

```
<?php
                $property             = $_POST['table_select'];
                $outlet               = $_POST['outlet_select'];        
                $pickyear             = $_POST['year_select'];
                $_SESSION['property'] = "$property";
                $_SESSION['outlet']   = "$outlet";
                $_SESSION['pickyear'] = "$pickyear";
            ?>

            <table width="100%">
                <?php
                    if ((isset($propery)) && (isset($outlet)) && (isset($pickyear))) {
                        echo "<tr><td><strong>No Selection Criteria</strong></td></tr>";
                    } 
                    else {
                        echo "  <tr><td bgcolor=\"#3F4039\">
                                    <p class=\"sansserif\"><b>RESULTS FOR: $property - $outlet - $pickyear</b></p>
                                </td></tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>

            <table width="100%">
                <?php
                    if ((isset($property)) && (isset($outlet)) && (isset($pickyear))) {
                        echo "<tr><td><strong>No Selection Criteria</strong></td></tr>";
                    } 
                    else {
                        echo "  <tr><td bgcolor=\"#3F4039\">
                                    <p class=\"sansserif\"><br><b>SCORE BREAKDOWN BY CATEGORY - $outlet</b></p>
                                </td></tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>

            <table class="fb_feedback_results" width="950px">
                <?php

                // multiple criteria selection
                $whereParts = array();
                if ($property) {
                    $whereParts[] = "Holidex = '$property' ";
                } 

                if ($outlet) {
                    $whereParts[] = "Outlet = '$outlet' ";
                } 

                if ($pickyear) {
                    $whereParts[] = "YEAR(date) = '$pickyear' ";
                } 

                $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS MCOUNT FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data");

                //BUILD THE FINAL QUERY
                if (count($whereParts) > 0) {
                    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode('AND ', $whereParts);
                } 
                //count($whereParts) > 0

                $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die('<p>Query to get total data from FB_Feedback_Card_Data table failed:' . mysql_error() . '</p>');

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
                {
                    $mcount = $row['ID'];
                    $mydata = stats("ALLMYRECORDS", "ALLMYRECORDS", "$property", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th class="header">Item</th>
                    <th class="header">Jan</th>
                    <th class="header">Feb</th>
                    <th class="header">Mar</th>
                    <th class="header">Apr</th>
                    <th class="header">May</th>
                    <th class="header">Jun</th>
                    <th class="header">Jul</th>
                    <th class="header">Aug</th>
                    <th class="header">Sep</th>
                    <th class="header">Oct</th>
                    <th class="header">Nov</th>
                    <th class="header">Dec</th>
                    <th class="header">YTD</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="result_desc">Ttl. No. of Feedback</td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['a'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['b'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['c'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['d'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['e'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['f'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['g'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['h'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['i'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['j'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['k'];?></td>
                    <td class="result" align=center><?echo $mydata['l'];?></td>
                    <td class="result_ytd" align=center><strong><?echo $mydata['total'];?></strong></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php
                    // end grand total stats
                    } 
                    ?>
            </table>
```